# How to add exisiting EC2 instances to an auto scaling group using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am using terraform to build my infra and trying to add an existing ec2 instance to a new autoscaling group.

We can do that using the AWS CLI [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html#attach-instance-aws-cli).

Is there a way to do it using terraform ?

Comment: terraform is not a simple tool to map aws-cli. It is for infrastructure as code. So do you need to run the terraform codes to repeatedly add an ec2 instance to ASG?

Comment: only once would do.

Comment: if you only need to do this once, have you tried adding the ec2 instance to the autoscaling group using the AWS CLI, and then importing the autoscaling group into terraform using `terraform import`?